# Por que no funciona el Select selected?

Tags: html, html-select, laravel-7

Quisiera saber por que no funciona mi selected, he hecho ejemplos como en w3school y otros ejemplos que contestan aquí mismo y no me funciona. este es mi codigo:

```
<select class="form-control" name="id_concepto_pago" wire:model="id_concepto_pago">
    <option value="" selected disabled>Elija una Opcion</option>
    @foreach($concepto as $con)
      <option value="{{$con->id}}">{{$con->descripcion}}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
```

PD. estoy usando livewire pero no creo que afecte.

Comment: A qué te refieres con no funciona, que comportamiento te da al momento?

Comment: si, perdón, lo que pasa es que yo espero la opción "elija una opcion" por default y me tira la opcion que está con el ID 1 de mi tabla

Comment: Así tal cual debería funcionar, sino aunque yo no uso livewire igual añade ese segmento donde esta el modelo `id_concepto_pago`

Comment: si, se que debería funcionar así, ese es mi principal problema, que realmente sé que debería funcionar.